# Adding supports post-tag in custom menu wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, tags

> How can I add support to add tags in post. I tried everything but still the post-tag option is not visible/appearing.

[image]

```
register_post_type( 'articles',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Articles' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Articles' )
        ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'excerpt','page-attributes','post-formats','custom-field' ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'articles'),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, you can get the custom post type with custom tag option.

Try this code,

```html
//* Create Custom Post Type
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_post_type' );
function add_custom_post_type() {

 register_post_type( 'members',
  array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name'          => __( 'Members', 'wpsites' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Member', 'wpsites' ),
   ),
   'has_archive'  => true,
   'hierarchical' => true,
                        'menu_icon'    => 'dashicons-admin-users',
   'public'       => true,
   'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'members', 'with_front' => false ),
   'supports'     => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
   'taxonomies'   => array( 'member-type' ),
                        'menu_position' => 2,

  ));

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_tag' );

function create_custom_tag() {
 register_taxonomy(
  'tag',
  'members',
  array(
   'label' => __( 'Tag' ),
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tag' ),
   'hierarchical' => true,
  )
 );
}
```

It will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add post_tag taxonomy to the register function:

```
register_post_type( 'articles',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Articles' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Articles' )
        ),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'excerpt','page-attributes','post-formats','custom-field' ),
        'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag'),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'articles'),
    )
);
```